# Running shell script while building docker image

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a custom package with `install.sh` script, which I want to run while building a docker image (meaning - put `./install.sh` inside Dockerfile). I could have ran it along with the container, but I want to have an image that contains the required packages (which are mentioned in the `install` script).

What I tried:

1. `RUN /bin/sh/ -c "./install.sh"`
2. `RUN ./install.sh`

It errors out saying -

> `/bin/sh install.sh not found`

or

> `/bin/sh ./install.sh not found`

This might be a repeated question, but I haven't found an answer to this anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not create `./install.sh` in your Dockerfile before you execute it with?

Comment: Share the minimal dockerfile which could reproduce your issue please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must copy your `install.sh` into docker image with this command in your dockerfile:

`COPY install.sh /tmp`

Then use your `RUN` command to run it:

`RUN /bin/sh -c "/tmp/install.sh"`

or

`RUN sh /tmp/install.sh`

Don't forget to make `install.sh` executable before run it:

`chmod +x /tmp/install.sh`

Comment: To make `install.sh` executable: `chmod +x install.sh`

Comment: I'm assuming 'tmp' is the folder from which I am copying install.sh @MSaadat

Comment: Does not work. I am still getting this error - 

`/bin/sh: 1: ./install.sh: not found`
`The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/sh -c "./install.sh"' returned a non-zero code: 127`
@MSaadat